# Clang on macOS - Set isysroot to a default location

Tags: c++, macos, zsh, macos-catalina

I have a MacBook Pro 16 running macOS Catalina (10.15.3) with XCode Version 11.4.1. I am trying to compile some C++ files and one of them has the header `math` because it is using some math functions.
Whenever I try to compile the file with `#include<math>`, I get a lot of errors. The compilation is done with `clang++`, which is found here:

```sh
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
```

---

> Compilation errors:

```sh
In file included from main.cpp:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: no member named
      'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: no member named
      'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:319:9: error: no member named
      'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/math.h:749:12: note:
      'finite' declared here
extern int finite(double)
           ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:320:9: error: no member named
      'isinf' in the global namespace
using ::isinf;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error: no member named
      'isnan' in the global namespace
using ::isnan;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:322:9: error: no member named
      'isnormal' in the global namespace
using ::isnormal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:323:7: error: no member named
      'isgreater' in the global namespace; did you mean '::std::greater'?
using ::isgreater;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:731:29: note:
      '::std::greater' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:324:7: error: no member named
      'isgreaterequal' in the global namespace; did you mean '::std::greater_equal'?
using ::isgreaterequal;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:760:29: note:
      '::std::greater_equal' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater_equal : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:325:9: error: no member named
      'isless' in the global namespace
using ::isless;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:326:9: error: no member named
      'islessequal' in the global namespace
using ::islessequal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:327:9: error: no member named
      'islessgreater' in the global namespace
using ::islessgreater;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:328:9: error: no member named
      'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:329:9: error: no member named
      'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
main.cpp:8:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto result = log(10.2);
    ^
main.cpp:9:9: error: no member named '__builtin_isless' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply '__builtin_isless'?
    if (std::isless(result, 2))
        ^~~~~
main.cpp:9:14: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
    if (std::isless(result, 2))
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/math.h:545:22: note:
      expanded from macro 'isless'
#define isless(x, y) __builtin_isless((x),(y))
                     ^
1 warning and 14 errors generated.
```

---

Fortunately, after [some research](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/45061#issuecomment-541010787), I found out that a solution is to use the clang++ compiler with the additional flag:

```sh
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

And that seems to fix the problem: my source compiles without any issues and I can run the executable.

However, I don't want to pass that every time I have to compile something.

**Q:** Is there a way to have that `isysroot` to always point into that SDK location?

I know I can create an alias to `clang++` in which I can pass the extra flag, but I was wondering if there is another way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you found an answer to your question yet?